# Angularjs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is my scenario. I am adding a block of code dynamically using javascript. Since its dynamic I have to bind it to my angularjs scope, which is done. But I have one problem here. One of the text box has a directive for it which works. But on change of any text box other than the directive text box for first time the scope.$watch triggers, later on it does not. Here is my code

```
$('.addNew').click(function(){
    var uniqid = Date.now();
    var html= '';
    html += '<section class="newItem" id="'+uniqid+'">';
    html += '<h4 style="margin: 10px 22px 8px 22px;color:#FF9900;border-bottom:1px dotted black;padding:1%;" > Grocery: <em>{{gName}}</em></h4>';
    html += '<div class="grosinput" style="width:0%;"><a href="#" class="stylish" data-uniqid="'+uniqid+'">-</a></div>';
    html += '<div class="grosinput" style="width:50%;">';
    html += '<lable style="color:#6699CC;font-size: 15px;">Name:</lable><input type="text" placeholder="Enter grocery item" name="name" ng-model="gName"/>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<div class="grosinput">';
    html += '<lable style="color:#6699CC;font-size: 15px;">Cost:</lable><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Cost" value="30" name="cost" cost-check ng-model="cost"/></div></section>';
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'grocery']);
    $injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {alert('t');
        $('.grocadd').hide().after($compile(html)($rootScope)).fadeIn(1500);
    }); 
});
```

Here is the directive

```
app.directive('costCheck',function($compile,$rootScope){
$rootScope.gName= "What did i buy?";
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){


                scope.$watch('cost',function(oldval,newval){alert(attrs.name);
                    if(attrs.name === 'cost'){
                        alert(oldval+'--'+newval);
                    }
                });

        }

    }
});
```

why is it triggering for other text box also

Comment: did any one see this code?

Answer (score 0):

Please note Angular relies on dirty checking which means it triggers all the watches to check if anything is dirty in order to update the View.

Either you should put a if condition to check `newVal` and `oldVal` are different to go ahead as:

```
scope.$watch('cost',function(newVal, oldVal){
  if (newVal !== oldVal){
    alert(oldval+'--'+newval);
  }
});
```

Or you can use `attrs.$observe` to observe the attributes as:

I changed the directive in the DOM from `cost-check` to `cost-check="{{cost}}"` and replace `$watch` with `$observe` as:

```
attrs.$observe('costCheck', function(val) {
  console.log(scope.$eval(val));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3018/